# PDF how showing up properly

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter

I have this simple code that takes a PDF, converts the pages into images and then displays them inside a ttk Notebook. This works only if I do not use a function to load the PDF. However this is part of a much larger program that lists many PDF forms; therefore, I need a function to load the PDF. It looks like the PDF is loading but its all grey.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I looked around but couldn't find anything related to the exact problem I am running into. I do want to use this method of displaying PDF forms because it's the one that looks the best when the PDF forms are filled in with information.

Please bear with me because I just started programming a month ago. There might be more than one thing wrong with my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from pdf2image import convert_from_path


def upload_pdf():

    # PDF is converted to a list of images
    pages = convert_from_path('/home/admin/PycharmProjects/ChecklistProject/Main_Genny_Bi-monthly_Operational_Check_M72QZZ1.pdf', size=(800, 900))

    # Empty list for storing images
    photos = []

    # Storing the converted images into list
    for i in range(len(pages)):
        photos.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(pages[i]))

    # Adding all the images to the text widget
    for photo in photos:
        pdf.image_create(tk.END, image=photo)

        # For Separating the pages
        pdf.insert(tk.END, '\n\n')


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('')
root.geometry("920x680+500+20")
mon_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
mon_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab_control.place(x=10, y=10, height=625, width=800)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

tab_control.add(tab1, text="Preview pdf")
tab_control.add(tab2, text="Other")

# ------- pdf text box with scroll bar

scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(tab1, orient=tk.VERTICAL)

pdf = tk.Text(tab1, yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set, bg="grey")

scroll_y.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
scroll_y.config(command=pdf.yview)

pdf.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# ------- button -----------------------------

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Upload", command=upload_pdf)
my_button.place(x=840, y=400)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You probably need to add `root.mainloop()` instead of `mainloop()` at the end

Comment: Do you want to add some text on the pdf? If not, use ```Canvas``` instead of ```Text```. Also, avoid importing everything (```*```) from a module. It can cause hard debugging issues.

Comment: PCM. Thank you. I have this correct in my program. So I corrected it here.

Comment: Ishaan < thank you. No I do not want to add text on the pdf. I just need to display them as is. Got it on the not importing everything.

Comment: Replace ```pdf = Text()``` with ```pdf = Canvas(root)```. Then replace ```pdf.image_create()``` with ```pdf.create_image(xpos, ypos, image="image path")```. Replace ```xpos``` and ```ypos``` with the pix positions where you want to place the image.

Comment: Ishann. Ok I will try your suggestions.

Comment: @IshaanJog You can use `Text` instead of `Canvas` to create scrolled images. There is no need to switch to using `Canvas`.

Comment: @PCM Actually most of the time, `root.mainloop()` is identical to just `tk.mainloop()`. The only time it will make a difference is if you open multiple `Tk` windows, close the first one, and then try calling `tk.mainloop()`. But it is true that it should be discouraged.

Comment: Ishaan: I couldn't make this work. I used acw1668 suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have used a local list `photos` to store the instances of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`, they will be garbage collected after the function completed.

You can either declare `photos` as global variable or use an attribute of `pdf` to store the reference of `photos`:

```py
def upload_pdf():
    # PDF is converted to a list of images
    pages = convert_from_path('/home/admin/PycharmProjects/ChecklistProject/Main_Genny_Bi-monthly_Operational_Check_M72QZZ1.pdf', size=(800, 900))

    # Empty list for storing images
    photos = []

    # Storing the converted images into list
    for i in range(len(pages)):
        photos.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(pages[i]))

    # Clear the text box
    pdf.delete('1.0', tk.END)

    # Adding all the images to the text widget
    for photo in photos:
        pdf.image_create(tk.END, image=photo)

        # For Separating the pages
        pdf.insert(tk.END, '\n\n')

    pdf.photos = photos  # used an attribute of "pdf" to store the references
```

Note that the text box is clear before populating the images.

Comment: acw1668: Thank you very much. This works for me. If I understand well, you first clear the text box, then run the loop and insert the images, then store the result in the attribute of pdf. I am not sure what the last step does since the images are already inserted. Would you mind to educate me a bit more on this?

Comment: As I said in my answer, `photos` is used to store the references of those images.  But `photos` is a local variable and it will be garbage collected if there is no other variable reference it after the function completes.  So I used an attribute of `pdf` to keep a reference to `photos` to avoid it from being garbage collected.